# FirebaseMLVision: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: firebase, firebase-mlkit, cordova-ios, google-mlkit

I'm developing cordova plugin for biometric authentication and now I need to integrate FirebaseMLVision with FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel. When I added the static frameworks into the project I got errors like this:

[image]

I have researched a lot about this issue and I haven't found the solution how to fix it.

I have linked the required frameworks like this

```
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/Firebase.framework" custom="true" embed="true"  /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework" custom="true" embed="true"  /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/FirebaseInstallations.framework" custom="true" embed="true" />  
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/FirebaseInstanceID.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/FirebaseMLCommon.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/FirebaseMLVision.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/GoogleAPIClientForREST.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/GoogleDataTransport.framework" custom="true" embed="true" />  
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport.framework" custom="true" embed="true"  /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/nanopb.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/PromisesObjC.framework" custom="true" embed="true" /> 
  <framework src="src/ios/frameworks/Protobuf.framework" custom="true" embed="true" />
```

UPDATE: I'm using the latest version of firebase ios sdks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel/FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel.framework and FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel/Resources/GoogleMVFaceDetectorResources.bundle to your project and please make sure that the target you want to add them to has a checkmark next to it, and that you've selected "Copy items if needed".

This page has the instructions:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

As mentioned in the instructions, please carefully review the README contained in the framework zip.